# Trouble with vector-to-vector neural network prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, linear-regression

I am beginner in machine learning, and I'm trying to make a network that predicts 8 outputs given 7 inputs.
This is a regression problem -- not classification.
After cleaning, I have about 3,000 data points. So far, nothing is really working.
Also, the "underlying function" is known to be very complex.
What do you think is wrong here -- should I try a different kind of network?

Here is my code (I dare to share):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model

# dataset
cancer = pd.read_csv('full_dataset.csv')
# inputs
input_cols = ['660nm', '685nm', '730nm', '760nm', '785nm', '985nm', '1050nm']
X = cancer[input_cols]
X.dropna(inplace=True)
X = (X - X.mean()) / X.std()
# outputs
output_cols = ['Collagen (%)', 'Total Hb (%)', 'Hb Sat (%)',
            'Lipid (%)', 'Water (%)', 'a (mm^-1)', 'b', 'Optical Index']
Y = cancer[output_cols]
Y = Y.loc[X.index]
# split into train and test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
# define model
# n1, n2 come from http://dstath.users.uth.gr/papers/IJRS2009_Stathakis.pdf
n = len(input_cols)
m = len(output_cols)
N = len(X_train)
n1 = np.sqrt((m+2) * N) + 2 * np.sqrt(N/(m+2))
n2 = m * np.sqrt(N/(m+2))
n1, n2 = int(n1), int(n2) # 116, 77
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n1, input_dim=n, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(m))
# compile
epochs = 500
learning_rate = 10**-3
decay = learning_rate / epochs
optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, decay=decay)
model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mse'])
# simple early stopping
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, patience=100)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5',
                    monitor='val_mse',
                    mode='min',
                    verbose=0,
                    save_best_only=True)
# fit model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=epochs, batch_size=32,
                    verbose=0, callbacks=[es, mc])

# saved model
model = load_model('best_model.h5')

true = np.array(Y_test)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
err = abs((true - pred)/true)

print(np.mean(err, axis=0))
```

Comment: `n1, n2 come from ...` This seems like a really strange way of doing this. Normally, what I see is using cross validation to pick the optimal number of nodes and layers. Is this a paper in your field? If not, I would ignore it.